# Query not executing parallely postgres

Tags: postgresql

```
with tab as
(select abc 
    from job_desc
    where id =5 and jd.jd_date >= current_date - interval '12 months' and jd_date < current_date
     and (loc is not null and loc != '')
  and workloads && '{Warehousing}'
    and skills && '{Customer Management}'
)

select abc, count(*)
from tab
group by tab.abc
order by count desc
```

Queries not executing parallely. I have my data partitioned monthly basis. Any suggestion.

Comment: What queries do you want to run in parallel? There's a single query in your example.

Comment: I have partitioned table. Parallel workers are getting used for the above query.

Comment: Lack of information. Please edit the question and add the `CREATE TABLE` statement and all the index definitions as well as the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query. Also, the PostgreSQL version is relevant.